# Automatic update of rows based on sysdate

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table TICKET_INFO

It has columns

1.TICKET_ID

2.BOOKING_TIME

3.STATUS

4.ENTRY_TIME

User can book tickets by selecting future time using an app.Suppose when booking, sysdate is 03/10/2020 01.55 PM and user chooses his time as 4.00PM, a record will be created like following.

```
TICKET_ID| BOOKING_TIME          |STATUS   | ENTRY_TIME
    1    |  03/10/2020 04.00 PM  |Pending  | 03/10/2020 01.55 PM
```

What i want is,as soon as sysdate passes 03/10/2020 04.00 PM,the record's STATUS should be updated to Waiting automatically.

100s of records can be created with different timings.

Whats the best practice to achieve this OnTime update. Trigger or any other way?

Comment: I would use trigger with `when` clause to prevent firing for all and only when the condition of `booking_time` is in future.

Comment: seems like you need to create a job or scheduler ?

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 - trigger?  The only triggering event in this scenario is the passing of time, and there is no trigger for that.

Comment: @EdStevens, my understanding was/is different than others with this question...when OP says `sysdate is 03/10/2020 01.55 PM and user chooses his time as 4.00PM`...I didn't understand it till now what it means...you cannot change the `sysdate` in any way.....I just took it in simple way like ..there is a ticket booking action and the `entry time` is the `current time` and the `booking time` can be in future which are two different fields...and by comparing I would update the `status` to `pending`...that's what I thought..would be nice if you can explain in short to understand it in right way..

Answer (score 2):

Realistically, the way to do this is to either create a job that runs periodically and updates the `status` or to create a view that does the calculation and query that (or a combination of the two).  You'd normally create a single job that runs, say, every minute (in which case the `status` might be set to `Pending` for a minute past the `booking_time`).  If you really only have the potential to have a couple hundred rows in this table, you could theoretically create a separate job for each row but that approach does not scale well.

The view would be relatively simple

```
create view vw_ticket_info
as
select ticket_id,
       booking_time,
       (case when status = `Pending` and booking_time < sysdate
             then 'Waiting'
             else status
         end) status,
       entry_time
  from ticket_info
```

If you want to create a job, you'd create a procedure that does the actual update

```
create or replace procedure update_ticket_status
as
begin
  update ticket_info
     set status = 'Waiting'
   where status = 'Pending'
     and booking_time < sysdate;
end;
```

and then schedule that using the old `dbms_job` package or, preferrably, the new `dbms_scheduler` package

```
exec dbms_scheduler.create_job( job_name => 'Update Ticket Status',
                                job_type => 'STORED_PROCEDURE',
                                job_action => 'UPDATE_TICKET_STATUS',
                                start_date => systimestamp,
                                repeat_interval => 'FREQ=MINUTELY; INTERVAL=1' 
                               );
```

You could do both and have the job that periodically updates the actual data in the table and the view that does the calculation at runtime for any rows that the job hasn't updated yet.  If you're really concerned about how long the status is still in `Waiting`, you could set the job to run more than every minute but that can get expensive and there are diminishing returns.  If you're processing data asynchronously, you have to accept some delay and if you have to accept some delay, it is pretty rare that a job that runs every minute (thus updating a row, on average, 30 seconds after the `booking_time`) introduces too much latency.

Comment: View option will not work as i am using Database change notification to send notifications to clients.Whenever the status changes user will get notification. I am not sure how good is Second option is. Running scheduler every minute? Will it create bottleneck?

Comment: you should experiment within your test db on your own whether bottleneck occurs whenever run the statements with real tables @Rajesh . But that's the way doing what you want.

Comment: @Rajesh - Will it be expensive?  Probably a bit.  Assuming you have an index on `(status, booking_time)` and there aren't too many `Pending` rows to scan, it shouldn't be too bad.  Of course, you are free to make the trade-off between timely notifications and query expense by adjusting the frequency of the job.  If you don't need notifications to go out within a minute of the `booking_time`, you could adjust the schedule to run every 90 seconds or every 2 minutes or whatever frequency makes sense.  You can create more complex schedules where you run less frequently during off hours, etc.